# What library does Google Chrome use to remove unnecessary stuff while converting an HTML page to PDF or just print it?

Tags: google-chrome

WHen we try to print a document in Google Chrome, it shows It's preview without any advertisements and any dynamic content like comments that might have been there.

What does it use to get rid of the extra unnecessary stuff from the DOM and convert it to a PDf when we save it as PDF ?

Is it a C++ library ?

Comment: It's not related to the PDF export function, printing it to a normal page will remove the unnecessary stuff too.

Comment: Yep. modified the question title.

Comment: Probably it will use print styles for the page where developers hide the adverts on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is pdfium, https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/master

This news article explains the library pretty well:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/06/google-chrome-pdf-engine-free

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can this be used in web application to generate PDF out of HTML. Is it fast ?